# Docker on Windows with Dart Docker Image

Tags: windows, docker, dart

How does this warning need to be addressed for a dart runtime docker image to be secure?  The docker image will ultimately be hosted in the google cloud.

> You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories."

Answer (score 4):

The [issue 20397](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20397#issuecomment-185471832) explains (credit: [Sebastiaan van Stijn - thaJeztah](https://github.com/thaJeztah))

> That warning was added, because the Windows filesystem does not have an option to mark a file as 'executable'.
>   Building a linux image from a Windows machine would therefore break the image if a file has to be marked executable.
>
> For that reason, files are marked executable by default when building from a windows client; the warning is there so that you are notified of that, and (if needed), modify the Dockerfile to change/remove the executable bit afterwards.

I like to add in the Dockerfile, after a `COPY`, a `RUN CHMOD +x aFile_I_Just_Copied`

Comment: Could you please update links you provides here. All the links were dead.

Comment: @developerbhuwan they are not dead. GitHub itself is dead: https://status.github.com/messages