# How to find which base image I need in dockerfile for my service

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a newbie when it comes to write docker file.
My question seems to be duplicate with below one.

I have gone through these links:
[Which docker base image to use in the Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588859/which-docker-base-image-to-use-in-the-dockerfile)

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

But these links don't teach how we can determine what base image is required for our project.
In my case:

My service uses java 8, Spring hibernate and connects to HANA database and also makes some rest calls. It also connects to some cache.

How to find, which base image is suitable in this case and how to write the docker file for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good answer to this; you could literally start `FROM scratch` and package everything yourself.

Otherwise, you need to trust the mantainers of the base images, such as `openjdk:8` and/or `maven:3` in your case since you are using JVM-based libraries. Not exactly clear why you were looking at Node images for Java.

"Connects to database/cache", "makes REST calls", doesn't matter, as almost all languages allow you to do this.

Worth pointing out that [spring-boot has native packaging so you shouldn't need to think about this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image)

Comment: In some dockerfiles, I see, they mentioned Ubuntu as base image. but you suggested openjdk:8. Should not I bother about OS as base image? Should I mention both "openjdk:8" and "Ubuntu" or "Linux" or "Windows". ? This thing I need to understand.

Comment: You can't run windows container outside of windows. And Ubuntu is a version of Linux, and there's no container named Linux that I'm aware of. You realize openjdk container itself has a base, right? Multiple, in fact. By default it's debian but some people use alpine tags for smaller file size footprint. Like I said, you could literally use any base image as long as you install all necessary dependencies, just like you need to in your host OS to run your project

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [distroless java image](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless/GLOBAL/java?gcrImageListsize=30) for deployment, preferably the `nonroot` variation.

For compilation/packaging/..., it depends whether we are using maven-wrappers or not. If we do, I would suggest using [eclipse temurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) (official successor of the [adoptOpenJDK images](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk)). If we need a full-blown maven, I would suggest the [official maven dockerhub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) (but the wrapper variation is preferred).